# How to Use ScrollTo() for div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to apply scrollTo() to mybody. but this is not working for me. Help please.

```
<div id="mybody" style="width: 5000px; background: tan;">
    <button onclick="scroll()">Click to Scroll</button><br><br>
</div>
<script>
    function scroll() {
        document.getElementById("mybody").scrollTo(500, 0);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Well when you click on a button which is inside the `mybody`, then you have already scrolled there, right?

Comment: It works when I write "window.scrollTo(500, 0);" but I want to use this function on specific div

Comment: Try this `offset = document.getElementById("mybody").getBoundingClientRect(); window.scrollTo(offset.top, offset.left);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you want to scroll horizontally

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mybody" style="width: 5000px; background: tan;">
    <button id="btn" onclick="window.scrollTo(500, 0);">Click to Scroll</button><br><br>
</div>
```

Based on your comment, scrolling is not happening because in your div#mybody there are no scroll bar attached. If you want to move button within component try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mybody").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#mybody button').animate({marginLeft:'+=500'}, 500);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mybody" style="width: 5000px; background: tan;">
    <button>Click to Scroll</button><br><br>
</div>
```